# Best way to port a mobile website to a mobile app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova

I have a website with a mobile interface (jQuery Mobile). I need to port it to a mobile app.

to make the website, I used Ruby on Rails.

I searched a lot and found many ways to port it such as PhoneGap, which seems to most viable solution.

However, I don't understand few things.

The most important part of my app will be the database. The iPhone/Android app will need to sync with the online website's database. So it need to store a local version and update every time the phone is connected to the internet.

How can I use PhoneGap with Rails? Can PhoneGap read Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [PhoneGap's FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/):

"A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. **However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. "**

So using web requests you can communicate with your rails application, which then does the database work and returns any results you need, making it an `API`. I would look into [these videos](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=37) for setting up a rails web service to communicate with your mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

> PhoneGap is an open source framework for quickly building
>   cross-platform mobile apps using HTML5, Javascript and CSS.

So, you can not package Ruby code with PhoneGap.

The way you can use PhoneGap with Rails, is writing a "Rails API". So your mobile app (PhoneGap) make requests to your API to get/set data from database.

My suggestion is to use an MV* Javascript framework like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap to send/receive JSON messages to/from API.